# Use Javascript to upload anything instead of only images

Tags: javascript

Here is my code where it is accepting only images that can able to view it is uploading. But i want to upload an jpeg image that was renamed from image.gzip to image.jpeg & this image i cant able to view in system as it is renamed from gzip to jpeg.it is not accepting here to load that type of images.. please help

```
function readImage(form, file, imageName, size, width, height, i, total){
    var flag = true;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();                                           
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) { 
    image.src    = _file.target.result;  
    alert("onload");           
    image.onload = function() {
    var w = this.width,
        h = this.height,
        t = file.type,                           
        n = file.name,
        s = ~~(file.size/1024);
```

Comment: Java tag removed -- this question has nothing to do with Java programming.

Comment: The question is unclear, a gzipped file renamed to a jpeg is not a jpeg its a gzip with a jpeg extension

Comment: ok thanks. In the above code only its accepting images i want to upload any file instead of only images. please help